# R tryCatch but retain the expression result in the case of a warning

Tags: r, error-handling

I have a long running function that might generate warnings in some cases.
When it does, I want to keep the result of the function, but add some diagnostic info to the result.

Something like this

```
x = tryCatch(
    someLongRunningFunctionThatMightGenerateWarnings(),
    warning = function(w){
        c(w$exprResult, list(diagnostics = "some useful info"))
    }
)
```

Is there any way to accomplish this with `tryCatch` without evaluating the expression for a second time in the warning handler?

Comment: I'm fairly inexperienced, so take this with a grain of salt, but I've faced a similar problem in the past. The only solution I could find was to nest `withCallingHandlers()` (which would append diagnostics for warnings but `stop()` for errors) as the `expr` within `tryCatch()` (which would only `stop()` for errors). Due to the limited scope of `function(w){...}`, the anonymous function for `warning`, I had to append the diagnostics to a global variable using a global function; or more generally, I had to call functions and modify variables in environments outside `function(w){...}`.

Comment: @Greg I can see how that would work. I typically don't like writing code that depends on mutating global values but in a pinch this would be a solution. Hoping there is an alternative though.

Comment: Perhaps you could simply mutate a variable in the environment that is the parent to the anonymous function, via `par <- parent.env(); par$var <- c(par$var, info_to_append)`.

Comment: Interesting idea

Comment: I'm still experimenting to see which is the parent environment to the anonymous `function(w){...}`.  I suspect it is the same environment as that containing `x = tryCatch(...)`, but I could easily be wrong...

Comment: I have the solution!  What do you want the structure of your `x` to be?  Do you always want a `list(result = `(return value from function)`, diagnostics = list(`(items of useful info)`))` to be stored in `x`?  That is, for a run of `someLongRunningFunctionThatMightGenerateWarnings()` that experiences no warnings, do you want `x` to simply be (return value from function), or do you want it to be `list(result = `(return value from function)`, diagnostics = list())`?

Comment: The latter as it leads to uniform access to the result

Comment: Also, do you want a _named_ list or an _unnamed_ list?  That is: `list(result = `(return value from function)`, diagnostics = list(`(items of useful info)`))`, or alternatively `list(`(return value from function)`, list(`(items of useful info)`))`?  Finally, should that second argument (`list(`(items of useful info)`)`) _itself_ be a named list, such as `list(diagnostics = `(items of useful info)`)`?

Comment: A named list with first name “result” and second name “diagnostics”. I should be able to adapt the solution from there.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68089753) you go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `base` solution with a custom function `myCatch()`, which has a form similar to `tryCatch()` (and identical to `withCallingHandlers()`). Feel free to adapt it, especially in the areas designated by my `# ADAPT...` comments.

By [request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68084740/r-trycatch-but-retain-the-expression-result-in-the-case-of-a-warning#comment120346194_68089753), I have also **Updated** `myCatch()` to accept a user-defined function `custom_fun`. Based on the `result` from `expr`, `custom_fun` will process any warning object thrown when evaluating `expr`, and its output will be returned as `diagnostics` (alongside `results`).

```
myCatch <- function(# The expression to execute.
                    expr,
                    # Further arguments to tryCatch().
                    ...,
                    # User-defined function to extract diagnostic info from
                    # warning object, based on output that resulted from expr.
                    custom_fun = function(result, w){return(w)}) {
  ######################
  ## Default Settings ##
  ######################
  
  # Defaults to NULL results and empty list of diagnostics.
  DEFAULT_RESULTS <- NULL
  DEFAULT_DIAGNOSTICS <- NULL
  
  # Defaults to standard R error message, rather than a ponderous traceback
  # through the error handling stacks themselves; also returns the error object
  # itself as the results.
  DEFAULT_ERROR <- function(e){
    message("Error in ", deparse(e$call), " : ", e$message)
    return(e)
  }
  
  
  ################
  ## Initialize ##
  ################
  
  # Initialize output to default settings.
  res <- DEFAULT_RESULTS
  diag <- DEFAULT_DIAGNOSTICS
  err <- DEFAULT_ERROR
  
  # Adjust error handling if specified by user.
  if("error" %in% names(list(...))) {
    err <- list(...)$error
  }
  
  
  #######################
  ## Handle Expression ##
  #######################
  
  res <- tryCatch(
    expr = {
      withCallingHandlers(
        expr = expr,
        # If expression throws a warning, record diagnostics without halting,
        # so as to store the result of the expression.
        warning = function(w){
          parent <- parent.env(environment())
          parent$diag <- w
        }
      )
    },
    error = err,
    ...
  )
  
  
  ############
  ## Output ##
  ############
  
  # Package the results as desired.
  return(list(result = res,
              diagnostics = custom_fun(res, diag)))
}
```

## Application

For your purposes, use `myCatch()` like so

```
x <- myCatch(someLongRunningFunctionThatMightGenerateWarnings())
```

or more generally

```
x <- myCatch(expr = {
               # ...
               # Related code.
               # ...
               someLongRunningFunctionThatMightGenerateWarnings()
             },
             # ...
             # Further arguments like 'finally' to tryCatch().
             # ...
             custom_fun = function(result, w){
                                             # ...
                                             # Extract warning info from 'w'.
                                             # ...
                                             })
```

and feel free to customize `error` or `finally` as you would with `tryCatch()`. If you *do* customize `warning`, your `diagnostics` will still be preserved in the output, but you will lose your intended output for `result` (which will instead become the return value you specified in `warning`).

If we followed your specific example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68090994), and used `myCatch()` like so

```
output <- myCatch(
  log(-5),
  custom_fun = function(result, w){paste(as.character(result), "with warning", w$message)}
)
output
```

then R would display the warning message

> ```
> Warning message:
> In log(-5) : NaNs produced
> ```

and give us the following `output`:

```
$result
[1] NaN

$diagnostics
[1] "NaN with warning NaNs produced"
```

## Further Examples

When we apply `myCatch()` to certain example `expr`essions, using simply the default for `custom_fun`, here are the results:

### Normal

```
output_1 <- myCatch(expr = {log(2)},
                    finally = {message("This is just like using 'finally' for tryCatch().")})
output_1
```

will display the custom message

> ```
> This is just like using 'finally' for tryCatch().
> ```

and give us the output:

```
$result
[1] 0.6931472

$diagnostics
NULL
```

### Warning

```
output_2 <- myCatch(expr = {log(-1)})
output_2
```

will display the warning message

> ```
> Warning message:
> In log(-1) : NaNs produced
> ```

and give us the output:

```
$result
[1] NaN

$diagnostics
<simpleWarning in log(-1): NaNs produced>
```

### Error (Default)

```
output_3 <- myCatch(expr = {log("-1")})
output_3
```

will gracefully handle the error and display its message

> ```
> Error in log("-1") : non-numeric argument to mathematical function
> ```

and still give us the output (with an error object for `results`):

```
$result
<simpleError in log("-1"): non-numeric argument to mathematical function>

$diagnostics
NULL
```

### Error (Custom)

```
output_4 <- myCatch(expr = {log("-1")}, error = function(e){stop(e)})
output_4
```

will kill `myCatch()` and immediately throw an error, with a ponderous traceback through the handling functions (here `tryCatch()`) within `myCatch()`:

> ```
> Error in log("-1") : non-numeric argument to mathematical function 
>
>   6. stop(e) 
>   5. value[[3L]](cond) 
>   4. tryCatchOne(tryCatchList(expr, names[-nh], parentenv, handlers[-nh]), 
>          names[nh], parentenv, handlers[[nh]]) 
>   3. tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers) 
>   2. tryCatch(expr = {
>          withCallingHandlers(expr = expr, warning = function(w) {
>              parent <- parent.env(environment())
>              parent$diag <- w ... 
>   1. myCatch(expr = {
>          log("-1")
>      }, error = function(e) {
>          stop(e) ...
> ```

Since `myCatch()` was interrupted, it `return`s no value to be stored in `output_`, which leaves us with

> ```
> Error: object 'output_4' not found
> ```

Comment: Very nice. I'd like to suggest a change. In my use case, I want my diagnostics to be (partly) a function of the results of the long running function. So I am thinking to change the warning part of `withCallingHandlers` to only set a flag that a warning was produced, then before returning the output, apply a user defined function with arguments `w` and `result`, and assign that output to the diagnostics.

Comment: Interesting...could you give an example?

Comment: I suppose you could set `DEFAULT_DIAGNOSTICS <- NULL` at the beginning of `myCatch()`, then simply do `parent$diag <- w` (instead of `parent$diag <- list("some useful info", w$message)`) within the inner `warning = function(w){...}`.  Doing so would store the `condition` object (here also a `warning` or `simpleWarning`) in `diag`, to have it ready for any calculations with your user-defined function `my_fun`, to culminate in `return(list(results = res, diagnostics = my_fun(diag, res))`.  If you want `my_fun` to be dynamic, we could even make it a parameter!

Comment: demo here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68090994/3760519

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why I can't get it to work with the paramter name `warning` instead of `mywarning` and not sure why it still prints the warning message, even though the warning is handled, but this serves to demonstrate the idea.

```
myCatch <- function(# The expression to execute.
  expr,
  # Further arguments to tryCatch().
  ...) {
  ######################
  ## Default Settings ##
  ######################
  
  # Defaults to NULL results and empty list of diagnostics.
  DEFAULT_RESULTS <- NULL
  DEFAULT_DIAGNOSTICS <- NULL
  
  # Defaults to standard R error message, rather than a ponderous traceback
  # through the error handling stacks themselves; also returns the error object
  # itself as the results.
  DEFAULT_ERROR <- function(e){
    message("Error in ", deparse(e$call), " : ", e$message)
    return(e)
  }
  
  DEFAULT_WARNING <- function(result,w){
    w
  }
  ################
  ## Initialize ##
  ################
  
  # Initialize output to default settings.
  res <- DEFAULT_RESULTS
  diag <- DEFAULT_DIAGNOSTICS
  err <- DEFAULT_ERROR
  warn <- DEFAULT_WARNING
  
  # Adjust error handling if specified by user.
  if("error" %in% names(list(...))) {
    err <- list(...)$error
  }
  
  if("mywarning" %in% names(list(...))){
    warn <- list(...)$mywarning
  }
  
  #######################
  ## Handle Expression ##
  #######################
  
  res <- tryCatch(
    expr = {
      withCallingHandlers(
        expr = expr,
        
        ###################################################################################
        ######### ADAPT the code STARTING HERE. ###########################################
        ###################################################################################
        
        # If expression throws a warning, record diagnostics without halting,
        # so as to store the result of the expression.
        warning = function(w){
          parent <- parent.env(environment())
          parent$warning_arg <- w
        }
        
        ###################################################################################
        ######### ADAPT the code ENDING HERE. #############################################
        ###################################################################################
        
      )
    },
    error = err,
    ...
  )
  
  ############
  ## Output ##
  ############
  if ("warning_arg" %in% ls()){
    diag <- warn(res, warning_arg)
  }
  # Package the results as desired.
  return(list(result = res,
              diagnostics = diag))
}


myCatch(
  log(-5),
  mywarning = function(result, w){paste(as.character(result), "with warning", w$message)}
  
)
```

Comment: You might have overcomplicated it a bit. Just start from my answer. Then, in the function declaration, simply put `mywarning` as a functional parameter: `myCatch <- function(expr, ..., mywarning = function(result, w){return(w)})`. The simply do `parent$diag <- w` within the inner `warning`. Finally, do `return(result = res, diagnostics = mywarning(res, diag))`. That's all! Just FYI, the only reason I ever resorted to `if("error" %in% names(list(...))) {err <- list(...)$error}` is because R won't treat the arguments in `...` the way it treats normal arguments like `expr` or `mywarning`.

Comment: Oh, don't forget `DEFAULT_DIAGNOSTICS <- NULL` as well.

Comment: I just updated my original answer to reflect your desired changes.